# Vuex causes routing problems

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using VUE 3.

I want to store token when user will log in successfully (I have added component Login.vue). For storing token I created folder "store" with index.js file at first:

[image]

And in **index.js** I have code like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);
```

Then I was trying to make this work in whole VUE App

My **main.js** :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import GAuth from 'vue-google-oauth2'
import store from './store'

const gauthOption = {
    clientId: '4584XXXXXXXX-2gqknkvdjfkdfkvb8uja2k65sldsms7qo9.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    // scope: 'profile email',
    // prompt: 'select_account'
}


createApp(App).use(router,GAuth, gauthOption, store).mount('#app')
```

And now -  **index.js** causes damage - I mean routing stops working when I run this line of code:

```
 Vue.use(Vuex);
```

I assumed that probably vuex renders before routing, but maybe there is any other reason? Or if I am right, how to make this work?

Comment: The question doesn't mention which Vue version you use. It's either `createApp` or `Vue`, one of them doesn't make sense for specific Vue version. You cannot use `use` with multiple plugins like you did. Consider checking docs on how core Vue api is used.

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you, I have already edited post - I am using `VUE js 3`. I am a little bit confused because some people are mixing `use` in `VUE 3` when I am looking for solution.

Comment: There's no default `Vue` import in Vue 3. You picked `Vue.use(Vuex)` from some Vue 2 example.

Comment: Am I supposed to do this by `import { createStore } from 'vuex'`?

Comment: See https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/ , it's in getting started section. Also another `use` needs to be fixed